# Problem in matching string with regex awk

Tags: regex, awk

I have this string to match using regex awk:

> if ldcTotal <> 0.000000

so i tried this:

```
if(match(linha, /^(\t| )*(if)(\t| )+(\<ldc\w*)[ \t]*([<>])[ \t]*(ldc\w*|[0-9]|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*))/) > 0){ 
            print "match: "substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH);
        }
```

but this just get expressions with > or < isolated.

What is the right regex?
Thanks

Comment: Use `<>` instead of `[<>]`. The latter matches either `<` or `>`, not the combined string.

Comment: This will lead to syntax error.

Comment: Why? `<>` has no special meaning in awk regexp.

Comment: Yes there is! <> meaning isolate a word like <var>

Comment: No `\<` and `\>` are word boundaries: the backslash is required.

Comment: Are you using GNU awk?

Comment: This is an example from the oficial doc: echo aaaabcd | awk '{ sub(/a+/, "<A>"); print }'

Comment: Yes i´m using gawk

Comment: That's using `<>` in the replacement, not the regexp.

Comment: We using this in our code for example: if(match(as_linha, /\<Return\>/) == 0)

Comment: I removed the parenthesis and now is running, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to add the parenthesis:

```
 if(match(linha, /^(\t| )*(if)(\t| )+(\<ldc\w*)[ \t]*(<>)[ \t]*(ldc\w*|[0-9]|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*))/) > 0){ 
        print "match: "substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need all the ccapture groups?

Comment: For replace the groups using gsub